# Create a New Stack Overflow Instance for Beginner Users and Content

Tags: feature-request, new-users, split-stack-overflow

Not sure if this has been discussed yet, I searched around but couldn't find any result so I'm just asking.

Would it help to split stackoverflow into two programming questions websites?

- One **would serve users above a certain rep threshold** (but be visible to anyone though) and (ideally) provide high-quality and challenging questions from trusted users who surely did their homework
- The other would serve newbie users and help rep-farming users to get what they want by helping others

I had this idea since the old reverse engineering forum which I used to visit years ago solved the spam problems by new users (reverse engineering == asking for a crack for many people) by splitting the forum into two sections and allowing basic users to just post into one of those until they gained some experience or showed efforts in learning their way out.

Comment: Even if the site was split into two, I highly doubt people would use the appropriate site to post their question.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I proposed a rep threshold to just allow trusted users to post on one

Comment: That effectively already exists, in the form of a bounty.  High rep users can use a bounty to draw extra attention to their posts.

Comment: Similar to what's happened with ELU and ELL; also MO and MSE.  It seems to have worked well in both those cases.

Comment: Why not just make a help forum for beginners? Because that's basically what you're asking for. [se] Q&A sites aren't really designed for beginner `plzsendmetehcodez` content. **In fact, they were explicitly designed not to be like that.** Go set it up, give people points for answering questions, slap on a bunch of ads, and then rake in the `$$$`. You're Welcome! `:D`

Comment: @Cupcake I agree but looking at the other posts here on meta it seems that many are about that problem, and unless there's a better solution it's a proposal

Comment: @Louis somewhat similar but I don't like the "hide the posts from users in a certain tier" thing

Comment: What of new users who are experts in their field and their question belongs on the "pro" partition? How do they post it there? Asking for a mess that cannot be reconciled...

Comment: This again brings up the question what does "professional and enthusiast programmers" mean?  But the suggestion put forth will not work to provide a place where the unprofessional and unenthusiastic programmers can thrive.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow reputation is not even close to being a perfect measure of your real-world experience.

What happens when those people come along who really do have well-researched, challenging problems clearly written up, but just have never signed up to the site before? You're going to stick them in the low-rep ghetto, and then they're going to get crappy answers and never come back. And their great question won't even help future readers, because it won't get a good answer.

What happens with someone who [just throws so many questions out there that he reaches 20k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)? He *still* ends up dropping stinkers in the guild hall.

If we're going to do filtering or segregation, the *content* is the only thing that we can do it on.

Comment: And of course, once you've taken the time to figure out what content is a stinker, and what is a rose, why bother keeping the stinker around at all.  Why not flush it down the toilet (which is of course what we're doing now).

Comment: I suppose exceptionally good questions might be migrated to the other website. If someone is terribly committed to gain reputation you can't stop him but he's likely to get downvotes in the high-rep website

Comment: Who's going to do that migration, @Marco? And why does the expert get stuck answering "my codez does not work. how fix?" questions?