# Is the content on Stackoverflow too advanced for beginning programmers?

Tags: discussion, meta

Being a beginning programmer myself, I have found much of the content (questions and such) to be far past my knowledge, even in languages I know the basics of (such as HTML). My question is, do you think the content is too advanced for people like me? If so, what can be done about it? If not, why do you think so?

Comment: Is the content too advanced in what respect?  Too advanced to be able to answer, too advanced to ask questions, too advanced to comprehend when you browse questions?

Comment: A mix of all, I think.

Comment: SO, like all things on this green earth, is too advanced for some people and not enough for others. I'm not sure about you.

Comment: `what can be done about it` do you think things in general would be better if you got better at programming or if SO "dumbed it down"?  What would/will happen when you get better?  Will/would SO still be of value then?

Comment: @Plutonix, that's the thing. What if we were to create a website for beginning programmers to ask questions.

Comment: arent there already gobs of such places - like Yahoo Answers, and lots of language/topical tutorial sites...  What kind  of answers do you think youd get in a beginner's ghetto?

Comment: Yahoo Answers is awful. You have people who troll constantly and give often incorrect advice. SO generates a more positive and professional atmosphere for me personally. I feel like I'm getting much better answers here than there. That's just how I feel.

Comment: That's exactly Plutonix's point.

Comment: @Woops see also [Create a New Stack Overflow Instance for Beginner Users and Content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253646/456814).

Comment: right, and how would a beginner's ghetto here be any different?  So you think Jon Skeet will browse it for questions?  DO you think anyone there would understand his answers if he did?

Comment: Oops, better reference: [Should we fork Stack Overflow for beginning programmers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381/456814).

Comment: the **easy** questions should be researchable...SO should be for the hard questions; you dont event have to understand why on an answer - if Jon Skeet says 'dont do X', then dont do it and someday you will understand.

Comment: @Plutonix A beginners ghetto on SE would be different insofar as people can vote on answers and delete questions. I can imagine you could have an SE for beginners questions without giving up to provide correct answers. Only there wouldn't be many professional answerer willing to do the job. That's the real problem. Nobody wants to answer beginners questions.

Comment: @Trilarion thats a fine point and i agree.

Answer (score 15):

To quote the help center (emphasis mine)

> Stack Overflow is for **professional** and **enthusiast** programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them

Ultimately Stack Overflow is intended for users to have a basic understanding of programming concepts.  You don't need to be an expert, but you are expected to understand enough to be able to understand the answers to your question.

Beginners are absolutely welcome, but users are expected to be able to operate on their own.  That means they need to be able to do research on their own and to be able to grasp the basics of the concepts they are asking about.  No one will hold your hand and no one will treat you differently just because you are a beginner.

Comment: Ah. I had no idea it said that. I need to read the fine print more often I guess. +1 for you sir.

Comment: @Woops one thing to remember is skill & experience level and "enthusiasm" level are mutually exclusive.  You can be a beginner and be a professional or an enthusiast, so do not let those words hold you back from participating.  But regardless a certain level of professionalism will be expected.  If you don't know how to figure things out on your own, and only when  you get stuck then turn to Stack Overflow, this might not be the site for you at this point.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Do you really mean "mutually exclusive", not "mutually independent"? I don't see any reason an experienced and skilled programmer cannot be an enthusiast.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes, I do mean "independent"... thanks for the correction

Answer (score 6):

Your concern does not make sense; what are you trying to do with the content? There's all kinds of problems and solutions on Stack Overflow, of all "levels".

If you have a programming problem, and you find a question that seems to be about that problem, but you can't understand either the question itself or the answers, then ask a new question, explaining your problem and *exactly* what you don't understand about the other posts.

There's no other concern that I can see. This isn't a course in school, it's not a social club, it's not a book you're reading chapter by chapter, and it's not a place to learn how to program. It's a place you look (or ask) when you have a coding obstacle that you can describe clearly in a few paragraphs. It's a huge archive of independent search results; hunt through it when you have some difficulty, and post a question if you don't find your answer.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I feel like you are right. It never says its for beginners, but I don't know. +1 for clarity

Comment: You're missing the point, @Woops. Beginner/expert/intermediate/guru doesn't matter. It's just well-formed problem statements with clear, concrete solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, much of it is too advanced for a beginner! -- thanks to the efforts of thousands of developers and hundreds of notable experts.

As an additional benefit, there is also a great deal of information for the beginner.

A more "beginner-oriented" Stack Overflow that can not answer the advanced, specialized and esoteric questions where people get stuck will not keep a large audience and would not continue to grow and be useful as new technologies are developed.

Comment: I think your middle sentence is gold. I've learned/figured out a thousand times the information that my profile activity would suggest here, just by reading the existing information. It works great - strangely - when I'm looking for something specific.

Comment: There's dozen, maybe 100s of examples of anything fairly common and basic, and votes help identify quality.  Why people won't read more of that stuff first before posting is beyond me.

Comment: I don't really agree with the last part. The beginners courses in university usually are the most well attended. Beginners tutorials tend to be simple, but there is not necessary mechanism keeping them old technology. In the old days people started learning Fortran, now they start with F# - still everyone is a beginner as some point. It's not clear in my eyes how a beginners SO would fare. If it wouldn't be so much work I would even try to see for myself and take part in such an endeavor. Teaching people how to programm in an Q&A format could be fun.