# Split Stack Overflow up into two websites serving beginners and experienced users

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow

This is another take on the [following question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253646/create-a-new-stack-overflow-instance-for-beginner-users-and-content). Questions from users new to programming obscuring the more well-researched questions is definitely a problem of the site.

As the answers on the linked question show, this cannot be solved by reputation, since very experienced users can still be new to the site, or weak in a particular area.

But what if we perform the split like mathoverflow/mathexchange did, so both beginners and experts know where to go to ask their question, depending on their experience on area of the question they're going to ask?

This will keep the votes more balanced, and I think this will keep both camps happy.

Comment: For downvoters, please leave some constructive criticism first.

Comment: I think you are getting both set of downvotes - regular disparagement with proposal (this is META after-all) and no research effort as linked questions discuss almost exactly the same thing, and have comment/answer "somehow it works for math" - but you don't explain why you'd think similar approach would work for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for leaving a comment. David Wallace commented on ELU vs ELL and MO vs MSE. I really don't know why the split worked for those sites, but SO does have a similar problem. I read the linked question and answers and people did not like separating the users based on reputation, so I'm taking that out of my question.

Comment: I agree that SO should be split, but for a different reason: it's much too large. There should be multiple smaller sites with different specialisms.

Comment: @MrLister You mean by language? I'm curious

Comment: Things like that. I once proposed a split into "web development" and "everything else", since about half the questions seem to be about web development.

Answer (score 5):

There are already about 4 tiers that roughly match your suggestion:

- http://stackoverflow.com - whatever programming related questions
- http://programmers.stackexchange.com - conceptual questions about software development
- http://cs.stackexchange.com - computer science for everyone
- http://cstheory.stackexchange.com - serious CS questions

I don't see how one can split SO into more layers (there are already several specialized sites like SharePoint, GameDev, CodeGolf and CodeReview for specific areas).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My proposal is more about splitting based on experience, not by the knowledge area. This is similar to the splitting of `cstheory` vs `cs` in the examples you posted above.

Comment: @simonzack - I see the separation of 4 sites above as "based on experience" already, but it looks like you mean something different. I think you need to clearly explain what you are proposing. Just be careful to avoid tiers by ability to search/read documentation...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't see how those sites show a separation "based on experience". Once upon a time my work had more to do with CS theory than practice but now I'm more into the practice of things than the theory. (I don't produce "proof of concepts" like the theorists do but actual working systems that people can use to do real work. I made the mistake of reading Mach's source code way back when. "Proof of concept" OS produced by theorists if there ever was one. Yuck!)